# How can I change Buffer size in Inputstream Reader?

Tags: android, web-services

I am using WebService to Get Data, but I only get 9 records of 62, I think this is problem of Buffer size, am I Right?

I use following code to get Data from WebService, and Webserivce is developed in php.

```
public JSONObject PostConnectionObject(String strUrl,ArrayList<NameValuePair> alstNameValuePair) {
        InputStream mInputStream = null;
        try {
            //This is the default apacheconnection.
            HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //Pathe of serverside 
            HttpPost mHttpPost = new HttpPost(strUrl);
            if(alstNameValuePair!=null)
            { 
                //post the valur you want to pass.
                 mHttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(alstNameValuePair));
            }

            //get the valu from the saerverside as response.
            HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpPost);
            HttpEntity mHttpEntity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();
            mInputStream = mHttpEntity.getContent();

          } 
          catch (Exception e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             Log.e(strTAG,"Error in HttpClient,HttpPost,HttpResponse,HttpEntity");
          }

         String strLine = null;
         String strResult = null;

        //convert response in to the string.
        try {
              BufferedReader mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mInputStream,"iso-8859-1"), 8);
              StringBuilder mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
              while((strLine = mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                mStringBuilder.append(strLine + "\n");
              }
              mInputStream.close();
            strResult = mStringBuilder.toString();
            System.out.println("Value of Result :"+strResult);
           } 
           catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              //System.out.println("Error in BufferedReadering");
              Log.e(strTAG,"Error in BufferedReadering");
            }
```

Comment: Please Send me your above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for InputStreamReader does not provide a way to set the size of the buffer it uses. The size of the buffer is up to the implementor.

In your code you use a buffer size of 8 for the BufferedReader(). So you could change the size of the BufferedReader's buffer by changing the 8 (second param of BufferedReader()).

I do not think that will help though. BufferedReader still returns entire lines even when its buffer size is much smaller than the length of the lines.

Your code looks straight forward and I suspect that the data is never being sent.

Comment: thanks user804056, really nice description and I was try to change 8 (second param of BufferReader()) to 16, 32, etc but you right there is no any effect, i got same number of records(Data). I can't total understand your last sentence can u explain it ?

Comment: The code in the question looks correct. If only 9 records are printed to System.out, then I suspect only 9 records were sent by the server and that you should next look at the code on the server.

I would use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to see if the server is sending back all of the records.

Comment: but when I open webserive link in web-browser so there is complete data is displaying , i don't know what is happing and why ?